# Как написать текст символами в консоль Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Язык программирования с++. Нужно вставить надпись

```
        cout << "███████████████████████████████████" << endl; 
        cout << "█─███─█───█─███────█────█─███─█───█" << endl;
        cout << "█─███─█─███─███─██─█─██─█──█──█─███" << endl;
        cout << "█─█─█─█───█─███─████─██─█─█─█─█───█" << endl;
        cout << "█─────█─███─███─██─█─██─█─███─█─███" << endl;
        cout << "██─█─██───█───█────█────█─███─█───█" << endl;
        cout << "███████████████████████████████████" << endl;
        cout << "██████████" << endl;
        cout << "█───█────█" << endl;
        cout << "██─██─██─█" << endl;
        cout << "██─██─██─█" << endl;
        cout << "██─██─██─█" << endl;
        cout << "██─██────█" << endl;
        cout << "██████████" << endl;
        cout << "██████████████" << endl;
        cout << "█───█─██─█───█" << endl;
        cout << "██─██─██─█─███" << endl;
        cout << "██─██────█───█" << endl;
        cout << "██─██─██─█─███" << endl;
        cout << "██─██─██─█───█" << endl;
        cout << "██████████████" << endl;
        cout << "█████████████████████" << endl;
        cout << "█────█────█─███─█───█" << endl;
        cout << "█─████─██─█──█──█─███" << endl;
        cout << "█─█──█────█─█─█─█───█" << endl;
        cout << "█─██─█─██─█─███─█─███" << endl;
        cout << "█────█─██─█─███─█───█" << endl;
        cout << "█████████████████████" << endl;
```

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что Юникод жалуется

Comment: Покажите код, пожалуйста!

Comment: @misdeed Каким образом лучше всего будет продемонстрировать Вам код?

Comment: @ лучше всего вставить код в вопрос.

Comment: @АндрейЧереватов вставить в вопрос

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно отображать и в UTF-8 (cp65001), но с этой кодировкой обычно больше проблем. Проще выводить в UTF-16, в этом случае не придется дополнительно возиться с кодировкой файлов и консоли, только поставить режим вывода стандартного потока:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    ::_setmode(::_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    auto const & sz_message
    {
        L"███████████████████████████████████" L"\n"
        L"█─███─█───█─███────█────█─███─█───█" L"\n"
        L"█─███─█─███─███─██─█─██─█──█──█─███" L"\n"
        L"█─█─█─█───█─███─████─██─█─█─█─█───█" L"\n"
        L"█─────█─███─███─██─█─██─█─███─█─███" L"\n"
        L"██─█─██───█───█────█────█─███─█───█" L"\n"
        L"███████████████████████████████████" L"\n"
    };
    ::std::wcout << sz_message << ::std::flush;
    ::_wsystem(L"pause");
    return(0);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С пиксельным шрифтом 8х12 (в этом случае еще не будет антиалиасинга и разрывов между строками):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, я был на правильном пути. Просто я не программист( Дико плюсую!

Comment: После вывода данной надписи символами программа перестает выполнять код, который написан далее

Comment: @АндрейЧереватов Может у вас на `::_wsystem(L"pause");` стопорится?

Comment: Убирал, не помогло

Comment: У C++ потоки **cout** , **cin** , **clog** перестают работать , если кто-то печатает в широких буквах как **wcout,wcin,wclog**. И наоборот. Всю прогу нужно переделать только на **wcout**.

Comment: а если юникод, то почему на консоль не выводиться емоджии?

Comment: @ТарасПрограммер Наверное потому что нет подходящего шрифта?

Comment: @user7860670 а какой нужен для корректного отображения?