# Как для консоли установить UTF-16LE

Tags: c, winapi, unicode, utf16le

Я хочу сделать корректный ввод/вывод юникод строк формата **UTF-16LE** в консоли **Windows**. Да, я знаю, что по умолчанию кодировка консоли - **866**.

Мне необходимо это для упрощения работы с файлами, в именах которых могут содержаться любые символы юникода. Чтобы организовать удобную работу с файловой системой.

Проблема в том, что **SetConsoleOutputCP()** не принимает код **1200**, который должен переводить консоль в режим **UTF-16LE**. В то же время, код **65001** корректно переводит консоль в режим **UTF-8**.

Comment: Консоль Windows поддерживает только однобайтовые кодировки.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите написать текст символами в консоль Visual Sudio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/842709/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-visual-sudio)

Comment: @VTT, нет, это не дубликат вопроса.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, откуда эта информация? Если это действительно так, тогда какой смысл было вводить для **SetConsoleCP()** и **SetConsoleOutputCP()** код установки **UTF-16LE**?

Comment: Это может и не совсем дубликат, зато, там есть решение, как выводить UTF-16

Comment: @VVT, возможно вы не заметили, но мой вопрос относится к языку C и WinAPI, а не к C++.

Comment: Во-первых там С++ и не нужен, существенные функции `_setmode` и т.д. - это С функции. Во-вторых в тегах стоит `cc++`

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://github.com/ClnViewer/LibWchar2/blob/77ea01779b38a22dc8bb07b7c44ffef67d2b3192/test/check_wchar2_MSVC.c#L150) - варианты шаманских танцев с консолью в Виндоус, есть режим ".OCP" он же ОЕМ, смотреть в его сторону.

Comment: @VVT, я не совсем понимаю, что происходит в описанном решении, но кодировка консоли не меняется, а так же имена файлов с юникодом корректно в консоли не отображаются.

Comment: @NewView, костыльное решение мне не подходит, тогда уж проще просто работать с **CP1251**, а если имя файла содержит то, что не попадает в установленную кодовую страницу, то делать виноватый вид и разводить руками... Но хотелось бы, конечно, найти нормальное решение. Ядро Windows NT везде где можно использует UTF-16LE, но стандартная консоль этот формат юникода не поддерживает? Интересно...

Comment: Стандартная консоль нормально печатает только через виндовые специализированные функции из их АПИ, в них реализована привязки к кодировке консоли и перекодировки. Всякие POSIX с утф'ами работают отвратного, и отображают как придется.

Comment: Как вариант, самому писать низкоуровневую функцию вывода на базе их АПИ, где и реализовать нужное. По крайней мере я пришел именно к этому мнению при попытке нармализовать утф вывод в консоли.

Comment: Из всего набора функций, у MS с утф адекватно работает `putwchar`, рекомендую начать с нее.

Comment: Смотрите сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105 (дубликат?)

Comment: Нет, не дубликат. Описанные в приведенной ссылке проблемы и решения я уже применял и достаточно хорошо знаком с ними. Я все же пришел к тому, что, по всей видимости, нужно использовать *юникодную* точку входа wmain(), но в **MinGW w64** с этим небольшие трудности.

Comment: @VladD По сути, автор справшивает, как вывести в UTF16 в консоль средствами WinAPI, без привязки к Visual C++. В том вопросе эта тема вроде не раскрыта.

Comment: @Максим: Поскольку для MSVC решение есть и как бы известно, имеет смысл указать в вопросе вашу среду.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: А, точно, я не подумал про MinGW, а в вопросе этого нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetConsoleOutputCP не принимает UTF16, потому что в этом нет необходимости. Для вывода в UTF16 независимо от текущей кодовой страницы можно использовать функцию WriteConsoleW:

```
wchar_t str[]=L". ąęėšų\nEnglish -- Русский -- Ελληνικά -- Español.\n";
HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, str, wcslen(str), NULL, NULL);
```

Что касается вывода через стандартную библиотеку С, для перевода его в режим UTF16 потребуется использовать нестандартные расширения компилятора, вроде _setmode в Microsoft CRT. Если ваш компилятор их не поддерживает, то ничего не получится.

Comment: Разве **wprintf()/wscanf()** не являются стандартными способами вывода/ввода?

Comment: А по поводу **UTF-16LE** и **SetConsoleCP()** - зачем тогда существует код 1200? В **msdn** написано, что этот код задает режим **UTF-16LE**.

Comment: @Максим Являются. Но практика, к сожалению, несколько расходится с теорией; под Windows, при использовании wprintf текст, по моим наблюдениям, не выводится в консоль в режиме UTF16, а преобразуются в текущую кодовую страницу. Можете сами проверить на примере моей строки с 4 языками - все символы, непредставимые в текущей локали, теряются.

Comment: @Максим https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Intl/code-page-identifiers `"Unicode UTF-16, little endian byte order (BMP of ISO 10646); available only to managed applications"`

Comment: Так и придется использовать однобайтовые кодировки, с ними проблем в самом деле меньше, чем с юникодом.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    {
        wchar_t file_path[1024];
        int const items_count_to_scan = 1;
        if(items_count_to_scan == wscanf_s(L"%s", file_path, _countof(file_path)))
        {
            wprintf_s(L"got file path \"%s\"\n", file_path);
        }
    }
    _wsystem(L"pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Пример работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня, почему-то, в описанной консоли текст **FфԆᗇ** в конце содержит символ **P** в квадратике, а сама консоль все равно находится в режиме **CP866**. Я очень ценю вашу помощь, но это решение не подойдет. Мне еще необходимо, чтобы в **argv** функции **main()/wmain()** была возможность принять корректные параметры в юникоде, например, ту же директорию запуска.

Comment: Возможно, это можно сделать, используя точку входа **wmain()**, но мой **MinGW w64** на эту точку входа ругается.

Comment: Это возможно сделать переведя из `char` в `wchar_t` и потом принт. Через функцию `mbstowcs` например.

Comment: Кстати, у меня данный пример не работает на консоли, жаль скриншот прилепить нельзя в комментариях.