# Символы Unicode выводятся по разному на версиях ОС

Tags: c++, windows, qt, консоль, символы

Мне нужно выводить в консоль символ █ ([код символа 2588](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)). Для того, чтобы он отображался правильно - добавляю строку `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);`, без неё получаю "тЦИ" вместо символа.

Также пробовал:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U8TEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U8TEXT);
```

Но так и не смог заставит это работать. Получаю:

> Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.

И сама проблема:

На моём компьютере с `Windows 10 Pro` символ выводится правильно, но на другом компьютере с `Windows 10 Корпоративная 2016 10.0.14393` получаю символ "рамка квадратика", то есть, как я понял, универсальный символ, если система не может найти нормальный. Шрифт и его размер в консоли на обоих компьютерах одинаковый (Lucida Console).

Как это исправить?

Comment: У вас же метка Qt, не пробовали с помощью его средств это делать?

Comment: @dIm0n можно поподробнее?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html

Comment: @Stus https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/unicode.html

Comment: Спасибо, я посмотрю

Comment: дубликат [Как написать текст символами в консоль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/842709/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-visual-studio/842734#842734)

Comment: `u8"█"`?… Не пробовали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось сделать без средств QT.

Можно использовать расширенный `cout` -> `wcout`:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); // добавить в main()
wcout << L"█";
```

Ключ *L* указывает на то, что следуюущая после него строка является строкой Unicode. В этом случае можно убрать строку `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);`, она больше не требуется.

---

Но в случае использования `wcout` придётся отказаться от обычного `cout`, иначе вы будете получать ошибку `Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.` (ну или я накосячил **:**)

Зато теперь символы выводятся правильно.

Comment: Лучше используйте кроссплатформенный Qt всё же или почитайте http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: думаю, что в этом случае Qt - это космическими ракетами по комарам.