# Как вывести текст по центру консоли и поменять его размер c++

Tags: c++, консоль

Как вывести текст по центру консоли и поменять его размер(а если возможно и шрифт) c++.

Comment: Средствами С++ (стандартной библиотеки) - нельзя. Можно средствами OS, либо посредством сторонних библиотек, либо предполагать что ширина консоли 80 символов (стандарт печатных машин). Уточните операционную систему и сценарий использования.

Comment: @Chorkov, linux, просто нужно вывести большую надпись в центр

Comment: можно псевдографикой, как в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/842709/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-visual-studio/842734#842734

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменять шрифт для части текста в консоли нельзя. Моноширинный шрифт для всего окна - это принципиально.
Можно написать часть текста "капсом" (ЗАГЛАВНЫМИ БУКВАМИ), либо выделить цветом/миганием/подчеркиванием.
Для этого используются оправляющие символы: https://habr.com/en/post/94647/

Чтобы вывести что-то по центру окна, нужно узнать его текущий размер:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369503/get-size-of-terminal-window-rows-columns
и добавить нужное число переводов строк и пробелов.

Comment: ну почему сразу  нельзя. Всегда можно звездочками текст вывести. А можно воспользоваться символами 0x2580-0x259F, легко сделать символы в два раза больше.