# Проблема с выводом символов в консоль

Tags: c++, visual-c++, кодировка, консоль

Получаю в ответ ? за место нужных символов, всё перепробовал пытаюсь сделать псевдо-графику в консоли C++.
Вот код:

```
    printf("╔════════════╗");
    printf("║            ║");
    printf("║            ║");
    printf("╚════════════╝");
```

В ответ получаю:

```
??????????????
?            ?
?            ?
??????????????
```

Проблема в том что за место этих символов знаки вопроса что это может быть?
Облазил форумы, нечего не помогло...

Comment: кодировка консоли и редактора разные. решается `SetCodePage(нужное)`

Comment: [Как написать текст символами в консоль Visual Studio?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/842709/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-visual-studio/842734#842734)

Comment: в–€в–€в–€в–€в–€в и дальше ешё 300+ штук)
Использовал код
```
    ::_setmode(::_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    auto const & sz_message
    {
        L"█─███─█───█─███────█────█─███─█───█" L"\n"
        L"█─███─█─███─███─██─█─██─█──█──█─███" L"\n"
        L"█─█─█─█───█─███─████─██─█─█─█─█───█" L"\n"
        L"█─────█─███─███─██─█─██─█─███─█─███" L"\n"
        L"██─█─██───█───█────█────█─███─█───█" L"\n"
        L"███████████████████████████████████" L"\n"
    };
    ::std::wcout << sz_message << ::std::flush;
    ::_wsystem(L"pause");
```

Comment: А при этом "\xDB" коректно показывает символ, как сделать что бы было так же?

Comment: Это вы использовали код из того ответа как есть, или вставили этот фрагмент в какой-то свой код? `"\xDB"` как раз не должно работать.

Comment: Попробуйте выводить подходящие коды смволов псевдографики в [cp866](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP866) (вроде бы это стандартная кодировка для виндовой консоли (cmd))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**##Ответ##**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <io.h> // символы расширенные
#include <fcntl.h> // символы расширенные
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"╔════════════╗\n");
    wprintf(L"║            ║\n");
    wprintf(L"║            ║\n");
    wprintf(L"╚════════════╝\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**###Немного о кодировках###**

Когда-то разработчики и стандартизаторы еще не думали, что компьютеры и интернет наберут такую огромную популярность и распространенность. Собственно тогда то и возникла потребность в кодировке текста. Кодировок очень много и надобно подбирать подходящею, иначе будут кракозябры и знаки вопросов. В зависимости от кодировки, символ получает разный код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Незачем копипастить чужие ответы, да еще снабжая их неправильными комментариями.

Comment: да, странно конечно

Comment: а сейчас, @user7860670 ?