# проблема с выводом символов в консоль с++

Tags: c++, windows, консоль, память

Здраствуйте! Хочу считать символы из файла и вывести в консоль используя именно Win32 API. По какой то причине символы в консоль выводятся неправильно. Кодировка стоит utf-8 и русские символы работают нормально. Я пробовал записать в файл считанные символы и всё прекрасно работает. Совершенно не могу понять в чём проблема. Помогите пожалуйста!

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

typedef wchar_t uchar;

const int SymbolSize = (sizeof(uchar));

int SendError(const char* message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

HANDLE OpenFileRead(const wchar_t* file_path) {
    HANDLE hfile = CreateFileW(file_path, GENERIC_ALL, 0, 0, 3, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (hfile == 0) {
        SendError("OpenFileError");
        return 0;
    }
    return hfile;
}

LPVOID MemAlloc(int bytes) {
    LPVOID Mem = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, bytes);
    if (Mem == 0) {
        SendError("MemoryAllocError");
        return 0;
    }
    return Mem;
}

int Readfile(HANDLE file, void* buffer, int bytes_to_read) {
    BOOL answer = ReadFile(file, buffer, bytes_to_read, 0, 0);
    if (answer == 0) {
        SendError("ReadFileError");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int Writefile(HANDLE file, void* buffer, int bytes_to_read) {
    BOOL answer = WriteFile(file, buffer, bytes_to_read, 0, 0);
    if (answer == 0) {
        SendError("ReadFileError");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    system("chcp 1251");
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U8TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U8TEXT);
    HANDLE file = OpenFileRead(L"C:\\Users\\rodio\\OneDrive\\Документы\\ha lol.txt");
    void* buffer = MemAlloc(20);
    Readfile(file, buffer, 12);
    uchar *ubuffer = (uchar*)buffer;
    std::wcout << L"Петя" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << ubuffer << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод консоли:
Текущая кодовая страница: 1251
Петя
晲⁲††††

C:\Users\rodio\source\repos\TmodloaderDecompiler\x64\Debug\TmodloaderDecompiler.exe (процесс 5480) завершил работу с кодом 0.
Нажмите любую клавишу, чтобы закрыть это окно…

Comment: Для начала — вас не смущает "*Кодировка стоит utf-8*" и "*Текущая кодовая страница: 1251*"?

Comment: Я просто не очень понимаю, какие у них отличия

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с выводом символов в консоль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1260069/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c)

Comment: Я уже пробовал данные методы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отличия в том, что UTF-8 - это UTF-8, а 1251 - это (неожиданно) 1251! Это разные кодировки! И выводить символы UTF-8 в консоль, которая настроена на 1251, и удивляться, почему выводится всё неправильно, ну это лол!

Однако в вашем случае 1251 тут вообще не причём! Ибо для вывода вы используете `wcout`. А это уже кодировка UNICODE, которой в Windows соответствует стандарт UTF-16LE (если не ошибаюсь). Опять же - другая кодировка, не UTF-8!

Что же делать? Есть такая функция WinAPI, как [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar). С её помощью можно конвертировать строку из UTF-8 в UNICODE. Собственно, вместо строки

```
std::wcout << ubuffer << std::endl;
```

напишите следующее:

```
int wlen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, ubuffer, -1, 0, 0);
wchar_t* wbuffer = (wchar_t*)MemAlloc(len*sizeof(wchar_t));
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, ubuffer, -1, wbuffer, wlen);
std::wcout << wbuffer << std::endl;
```

Должно сработать (но есть нюанс - см. p.p.s ниже). Кстати, рекомендую не полагаться на флаг `HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY` при создании буфера, а обнулять символ в конце прочитанных данных непосредственно после вызова [`ReadFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile). Для этого параметер `lpNumberOfBytesRead` окажется весьма полезен.

P.S. Вызовы `system("chcp 1251")` и `_setmode()` не нужны.

P.P.S. Для справки. UTF-8 - это кодировка с символами **переменной длины**! Так, латинские буквы, цифры и прочие стандартные символы занимают один байт, и их коды полностью совпадают с ASCII. А вот русские буквы кидируются уже большим числом байт, и их коды радикально отличаются и от ASCII (что логично), и от UTF-16! И вообще, длина кодов символов в UTF-8 варьируется от 1 до 6 байт. Так что прочитав из UTF8-файла 12 байт, вы не обязательно прочитали 12 символов. А если это русский текст, то точно не 12, а меньше. А последний прочитанный символ, к тому же, может оказаться ещё и битым (прочитанным частично). Советую это учесть.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Правда, у меня без _setmode(); текст вообще не выводится.

Comment: @Qzim 45 а вот это уже странно, почему без _setmode() не выводится. Значит что-то не так.