# Как вывести ascii символы с txt файла? C++

Tags: c++, ascii, txt

Всем привет. Хочу сделать свой проект с ascii символами. Чтобы его реализовать, мне нужно как-то отрисовать карту в консоле. Видел, что другие просто делают двумерный массив символов и в нем сохраняют. Но я пошел по другому пути: пробовал сначала сделать карту в txt файле и далее просто считать её, но вместо того, чтобы выводить *░*, оно делает каракули, например, **тЦС**.

Вывожу с файла информацию так:

```
void level::load_level(string file_name)
{
     ifstream file;
     file.open(file_name);

     if (file.fail())
     {
         perror(file_name.c_str());
         system("pause");
         exit(1);
     }

     string line;
     while (getline(file, line))
     {
         level_data.push_back(line);
     }

     file.close();
}

 void level::print()
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < level_data.size(); i++)
         cout << level_data[i] << endl;
     cout << endl;
 }
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой, если да, то как её можно решить? Или вы можете посоветовать другой вариант для сохранения и вывода в консоль

P.S Работаю в VS 2019

Comment: ░ не является ascii символом, А для отрисовки в консоль превдографики следует завести одномерный массив символов wchar_t см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/842709/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-visual-studio/842734#842734 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811009/c-vs-%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8/811056

Comment: Возможно, я ошибаюсь, но этот символ, ░, тут есть под индексом 177 [ссылка](https://www.asciitable.com/). А можно вот эту псевдографику в файл запихнуть и оттуда считать?

Comment: Там под названием "Extended ASCII Codes" расписана https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437 А вообще это юникод символ U+2591.

Comment: Символы псевдографики использовались в MS DOS. Следовательно, для того, чтобы символ '░' отображался именно как '░', а не '°' или ещё как-нибудь, необходимо использовать либо кодировку 866 (применялась в DOS), либо Юникод.